# How to create a subset of a dataframe by choosing NaN values from one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like so:

[image]

I want to choose the rows where floor_count is not NaN. I tried something like:

`full_train_df[full_train_df["floor_count"]=!np.nan]` . But, it doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

Comment: `full_train_df[~full_train_df['floor_count'].isna()]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem worked thanks! Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not check with `!= np.nan`, since `np.nan` is not equal to `np.nan`. You can check with [**`.isna()`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html), so we can here filter out the `NaN`s with:

```
full_train_df[~full_train_df['floor_count'].isna()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) to peformance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
full_train_df[full_train_df['floor_count'].notna()]
```